# Is ptr = free(ptr), NULL safe?

Tags: c, variable-assignment, comma-operator, symmetry

I'm writing code like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    void *kilobyte;
    kilobyte = malloc(1024);
    kilobyte = NULL, free(kilobyte);
    return 0;
}
```

for symmetry, which is nice. But I've never seen anyone else using this idiom before, so I wonder if this might actually be unportable/unsafe, despite this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) quote:

> In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type).

---

Edit: mixed up the order. Now it compiles on `gcc` without any warnings.

Comment: `free` does not return a value, thus the line is bad style. The code is not even less typing, use the standard ideom.

Comment: AFAIK, comma operator discards `free` value, which is `void`, and uses `NULL` is instead. And it **is** less typing if your style demands consistently assign pointers to NULL after freeing them.

Comment: There is no value to discard! Did you try to compile this before asking? Did you find proof in the standard this is legal or illegal? Please cite the section. (oh, and I did try with gcc).

Comment: `void` is **not** a value! This is about C! There is no `void` type.

Comment: Well, yeah, but since it's discarded... I don't know if it matters.

Comment: Btw. the citation is wrong. Check the standard! Don't use non-autoritative resouces for language questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401062/comma-operator-and-void-expression

Comment: @tkausl: That is about C++, a different language.

Comment: if you try to compile it this will be the result `error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
`

Comment: @pfannkuchen_gesicht I just tried OP to compile himself to see the result. Just telling someone the result is a bad idea.

Comment: @Olaf No it isn't.

Comment: There is no symmetry.

Comment: Sorry mixed it up. Now it compiles

Comment: @tkausl: Did you notice the tags? (The WP citation is wrong anyway)

Comment: Yes, and now it invokes undefined behaviour without you being notified.

Comment: Run your "perfect" code in a debugger!

Comment: @Olaf see the answer dbush. That works fine and is actually quite neat, considering you safe some writing and a line and get your pointer nulled.

Comment: @pfannkuchen_gesicht: That was not my point! Yet it is uncommen in professional code, as it is less clear than a simple `free(p); p = NULL;`. But fee free to use it, I hardly see your code anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By doing this:

```
kilobyte = NULL, free(kilobyte);
```

You have a memory leak.

You set `kilobyte` to NULL, so whatever memory it was pointing to is no longer referenced anywhere.  Then when you do `free(kilobyte)`, you're effectively doing `free(NULL)` which performs no operation.

Regarding `free(NULL)`, from the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

> **7.22.3.3 The `free` function**
>
> 1.
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
> void free(void *ptr);
> ```
>
> 2. The `free` function  causes  the  space  pointed  to  by `ptr` to  be
>   deallocated,  that  is,  made available for further allocation.  **If
>   `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs**.  Otherwise, if the  argument 
>   does  not  match  a  pointer  earlier  returned  by  a  memory 
>   management function,  or  if  the  space  has  been  deallocated  by 
>   a  call  to `free` or `realloc`,  the behavior is undefined.

As for your original code before the edit:

```
kilobyte = free(kilobyte), NULL;
```

The problem with this is that the `=` operator has higher precedence than the `,` operator, so this statement is effectively:

```
(kilobyte = free(kilobyte)), NULL;
```

This tries to set a variable to `void` which is not allowed.

What you probably indented to do is this:

```
kilobyte = (free(kilobyte), NULL);
```

This frees the pointer, then sets the pointer to NULL.

As mentioned by Olaf in the comments, rather than doing everything in one line, it would be preferable to do this instead:

```
free(kilobyte);
kilobyte = NULL;
```

Doing this is more clear to the reader than condensing the code into something others might not understand, and (as you've now seen) is less error prone.